# Extracting data from a pdf, turning into a QR code and inserting the pdf and QR codes into a word.doc

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, ms-word

In a nutshell - i want to take an existing PDF and read just the tool numbers and add barcodes for the tool number to the PDF/Word doc. since word will convert pdf's.

I need some ideas to get data from a PDF which is a printout of an access database. 
So we pull up the doc after filling out a few things on the form (access) then we print it. well this database is not available for me to play around with so i wanted to print to a PDF and then read the "TOOL NUMBERS"using TABULA or something similar then export to excel. turn them into either 39extended barcode or QR code. then import into word the original PDF and insert the BAR CODE under the tool number and print.  yes crazy as it sounds this is the only work around i can come up with. 
i wrote the excel column with tool numbers to QR code (.png's) "toolnumber.png". or is there a way for me to find the MDB file and extract data from that? the column in that datafile should be "ToolNumber".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ultimately want the output in Excel, there's no need to involve Word or PDFs in the process at all - simply query the Access DB directly from Excel and format the output as required.

Comment: i will see if i have permission to that file. ill give an update.